# Parsing ssv file

Tags: c

This is my main file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "ssv.c"

int main() {

    int i,length,acct;
    float amnt;
    char data[1000], record[1000];

    FILE *x = fopen("students.ssv","rt");

    while(!feof(x)) {
        for (i = 0; data[i] != '\n'; i++) {
            record[i] = data[i];
            length = i + 1;
        }
        record[length] = '\0';
        parse(record,&acct,&amnt);
        fgets(data,999,x);
    }

    fclose(x);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my ssv.c file

```
#include<stdio.h>

void parse(char record[], int *acct, float *amnt){
    sscanf(record,"%d %f",acct,amnt);
}
```

For some reason, these two programs are not working very well together. I am still getting used to modular programming. I keep getting the messages "undefined reference to main" and "multiple definition of".

My main goal here is to parse a file like

```
100 -10.5
13 -2.4
```

into corresponding fields. Please advise!

Comment: Missing the important bits like how you are trying to compile/link.

Comment: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: You never call `parse()`. And the loop in the main file is using `data` before it has read anything into it.

Comment: just updated it

Comment: I fixed your indentation so the program is readable. Why did you undo that?

Comment: "I keep getting the messages "undefined reference to main" and "multiple definition of".". Please show us the exact errors and how you are compiling. Makes it difficult if you don't provide all the relevant info.

Comment: gcc ssv.c
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Also, I did an fgets(data, 999, x) before the while loop. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

The first iteration of the `while` loop uses `data` before it has read the line. It should be:

```
    while(fgets(data, sizeof data, x)) {
        parse(data,&acct,&amnt);
    }
```

You don't need to subtract 1 from the size of `data` when calling `fgets()`.

There's no reason to copy `data` to `record`. You can simply parse `data` (the `parse()` function will ignore the newline). `fgets()` ends the string with a null terminator, you don't need to add it yourself.

`#include` should only be used for `.h` files, not `.c` files. You combine object files using the linker. So get rid of `#include "ssv.c"`, replace it with `#include "ssv.h"`. This file should just contain a declaration of `parse()`.

```
void parse(char record[], int *acct, float *amnt);
```

Compile the two programs using:

```
gcc main.c ssv.c
```

Or you can compile each file separately then link them:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c ssv.c
gcc main.o ssv.o
```

Comment: How can I use gcc -c here?

Comment: Should I check for !feof()??

Comment: No, `fgets()` returns `NULL` when it gets to EOF and the loop stops. Didn't you read the link I posted above?